# Check for a particular substring pattern within a string and get all of its matches

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I am trying to search in a string and trying to extract a particular thing from the string.
here are the example i am trying to solve.

```
const string = 'xtyzjdjgdjf +91888123455, +918885558565 +916885123456, +911234569870'
i am trying to extract only '+91888123455, +918885558565 +916885123456, +911234569870'
```

but the number is dynamic and it changes as per the response

Comment: How do you know what you would like to extract?

Comment: @Rastalamm i just want to extract the numbers from the string and these numbers will be dynamic

Comment: @luciferluci ... and how about the optional commas/whitespaces? From how the Q. was presented it looks like this stuff should be preserved exactly as it comes with the original input.

Comment: @PeterSeliger i am expecting these types of inputs from the users may be they put commas/ and maybe not that's why i have added in this way.

Comment: @luciferluci ... *"... may be they put commas/ and maybe not ..."* ... but does this mean one needs to preserve this meta information or would one not be better off with suppressing it and just go with the pure number?

Comment: @luciferluci - you should update your question with multiple examples of inputs and outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

about the pattern of the used regex ... [`/\+\d+,{0,1}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/UJ7bA0/1) ...

1. `\+` ... match a single mandatory `+` sign ... followed by ...
2. `\d+` ... at least one digit (or a sequence of digits) ... followed by ...
3. `,{0,1}` ... a single but optional comma.
4. `g` ... search/match the pattern globally.

```js
function extractValidNumberSequences(str) {
  return str.match(/\+\d+,{0,1}/g).join(' ');
}

const test = `
  xtyzjdjgdjf +91888123455, +918885558565 +916885123456,,, +91123456987 dsjk jjd
  sag sadgsadj 43865984 dsjghj, +918885558565 +916885123456,,, +91123456987 dsjk
`;

console.log(`extractValidNumberSequences(test) : "${ extractValidNumberSequences(test) }"`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const string = 'xtyzjdjgdjf +91888123455, +918885558565 +916885123456, +911234569870'
const extractMe = '+91888123455, +918885558565 +916885123456, +911234569870'
    
if (string.includes(extractMe)) {
   // extractMe is what you want to extract
}
```

Comment: sorry but these numbers in the string will be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using Regex: `/\+\d*/g`.
This Regex is searching for all the strings that starts with `+` and have 0 or more numbers after that.

```js
const string = 'xtyzjdjgdjf +91888123455, +918885558565 +916885123456, +911234569870';

const result = [...string.matchAll(/\+\d*/g)] // Get all the regex matches
  .map(([text]) => text) // Grabbing the first element in the array which is the text
  .join(','); // Join the text together

console.log(result);
```

### Resources

- [String#matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)
- [regexr](https://regexr.com/) - A great tool to visualise and understand Regex expressions

Comment: This will return a match even if the substring is not present.

Comment: Or just:

```js
const string = 'xtyzjdjgdjf +91888123455, +918885558565 +916885123456, +911234569870';

const result = string.match(/\+\d*/g).join(',');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @baradm100 ... this approach/regex doesn't cover the OP's need (at least it looks like it from the Q.) of preserving commas/whitespaces as provided with the original string ... OP wants `'+91888123455, +918885558565 +916885123456, +911234569870'`.

Answer (score 0):

var stringVal = "'xtyzjdjgdjf +91888123455, +918885558565 +916885123456, +911234569870".replace('xtyzjdjgdjf','');

console.log(stringVal);   //prints: +91888123455, +918885558565 +916885123456, +911234569870

For all occurrences to be discarded use:
Eg --
var ret = "data-123".replace(/data-/g,'');
PS: The replace function returns a new string and leaves the original string unchanged, so use the function return value after the replace() call.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me get this straight: You're looking to extract a sequence of numbers from a string beginning in a "+" symbol and ending in a "," character?

The way you could do that is looping through the string.

```js
let Raw = "udhaiuedh +34242, +132354"

function ExtractNumbers(ToDecode) {
    let StartSet = ["+"]
    let EndSet = [","," "]
    let Cache = ""
    let Finished = []
    
    for (Char of ToDecode) {
        if (StartSet.includes(Char)) {
            if (Cache.length != 0) {
                Finished.push(Cache)
            }
            Cache = ""
        } else if (EndSet.includes(Char)) {
            if (Cache.length != 0) {
                Finished.push(Cache)
            }
            Cache = ""
        } else {
            if (Number(Char)) {
                Cache = Cache + String(Char)
            }
        }
    }
    if (Cache.length != 0) {
        Finished.push(Cache)
    }
    return Finished
}

console.log(ExtractNumbers(Raw))
```

It's not perfect, but a nice example to get you started :)